# Interest in Biblical Archaeology

Tags: archaeology

Why is it that I see a lot of non-Jewish people interested in the "Real" location of Har Sinai, the "Real" red sea crossing etc.? But, I don't see that sort of interest among us?

Is it possibly because, we see Judaism, as a day to day element?
While the non-Jews look at it as a archeological/ historical episode?

Comment: At least regarding Mount Sinai, the common idea I’ve heard is that we shouldn’t care where it is. There’s nothing holy about it anymore, it was merely the location where the Torah would be transferred. The only important thing is the Torah, while the mountain doesn’t have any innate holiness. And regarding other historical sights, there’s no real need to know where they are. Sure it might be cool to let’s say stand by the Red Sea and say “this is where my ancestors stood thousands of years ago,” but practically there’s no reason to find these places

Comment: Judaism cares about the _soul_ of the matter, not the physical. We don't need to know what Moshe looked like, we need to know _who_ he was and what he taught us. We need to know how Hashem took us out of Egypt, and why, not _where_.

Comment: @curiousyid I'm pretty sure you say a bracha if you see the spot on the Red Sea.  Also my personal theory on Har Sinai https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/124271/11532

Comment: @RabbiKaii I highly disagree with you on that. Proper understanding of geography, culture, languages etc is vital for understanding at least pshat levels of Tanach, midrash, mishna, gemara and many other sources. How will you understand what the text is trying to convey if you don't understand what the text is even saying? Understanding the physical brings understanding the spiritual.

Comment: @Harel13 These comment sections don't do justice to these topics. I agree with what you said, especially when there _is_ a specific reason to know about the physical, such as a halachic question. It's hard to blanket these statements, but in the theme of the question itself, it's true - we aren't concerned about where Har Sinai is, where Ur Kasdim is, what Moshe looked like, etc. and davka because we care about the ruchni, and the tachlit, not the gashmi (itself), unless it is nogeah

Comment: @RabbiKaii Learning all those things is no worse than ben sorer umoreh. It's Torah and you must learn it all. It doesn't have to be spiritually tantalizing. We don't traditionally only learn things that are nogeah.

Comment: @DoubleAA If it's Torah, it's Torah, if not, not. I'd venture it's not Torah to know what skin colour Moshe had. Maybe I'm wrong, and there's a midrash on it! Also, let's be clear, I am not saying it's wrong to have an interest in Jewish archaeology. On the contrary, even when it's not important for some halachic or hashkafic matter, it's extremely important for connecting to our people and our tradition and our chizuk. I think you and me speak a bit of a different language, we keep having these disagreements and I think we need to slow down a bit and make sure we are understanding eachother.

Comment: For instance, I think you took my word nogeah too literally. I meant, nogeah to some halachic or hashkafic matter. Ben sorer u'morer is nogeah in that sense, to mitzvot and halachot. I didn't mean nogeah in the sense of "mitzvot that apply today". Sorry. I go back to my previous point - these comment sections are too small.

Comment: @RabbiKaii In the context of your interest in Chassidut, it's surprising to read your opinion here. Are you aware that the Lubavitcher Rebbe took great pains to re-design the pictured route through the Sinai peninsula for one of the childrens magazines being published under his supervision? His editorial changes were to coincide with the geography and archeology. As I recall, this story may even appear on Chabad.org. Regarding general interest in biblical archeology, this relates to the recovery of the ashes of the red heifer from Moshe together with the container of mannah and Aharon's staff.

Comment: @YaacovDeane let's wind back to the actual question. Why is there little interest in the Torah about the exact location of Sinai. I think, overall, that is an accurate picture, and I gave what I believe is the principle that drives that. There are 1000 wonderful examples (exceptions, or within the principle itself) of times where Torah sources and Rabbonim found hugely important reasons to elaborate on the physical side of things. Maybe I am just plain wrong, but I feel like I probably shouldn't have said anything due to the confusion that is arising :)

Comment: @RabbiKaii The presumption from the OP is incorrect. Shas is filled with all kinds of efforts to determine actual and exact locations and also to mention geological remnants of specific events that were still present. Think like the translation of the Torah into 70 languages monument. The comment from Harel13 above is IMO correct. For context, review the HaYom Yom for the 7th of Kislev said just a few days ago.

Comment: @YaacovDeane ok, I will try to understand your point of view, and bli neder review that HaYom Yom. Do you feel there is nothing correct about my point? I will note that while I haven't come close to seeing all of shas, I don't think I've ever seen a passage trying to determine the location of something out of simple interest, there's always some reason nogeah to the sugya.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Take a look at the discussion of the location of Moshe's burial place in Shas and elsewhere. https://www.sefaria.org/topics/moses-death-and-burial?tab=sources       See also: https://www.thetorah.com/article/the-unknown-yet-known-place-of-moses-burial

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141113/discussion-between-rabbi-kaii-and-yaacov-deane).

Comment: I apologise to all for the confusion. I am still holding on to the possibility that I have been misunderstood, mainly because what all those who disagree have written, I feel I agree with, especially @Harel13, and fits with what I say, but I would love to get to the bottom of the issue and happy to be proven wrong. There's a chat started now, feel free to weigh in

Comment: In my understanding, after the development of [mostly Christian] Biblical criticism in Europe in the 19th century, the question of its historicity became very critical. Unlike Christianity, Rabbinic Judaism is not based on the historicity of the scriptural narrative or Biblical literalism. For example, very few Orthodox Jews still hold that the Earth is flat, and that there's a firmament (a dome) above it with windows, from which God rains upper waters, or that the World was created in 6 literal days, Noah's flood was a historical fast, and the whole humanity stemmed from 3 brothers.

Comment: @AlBerko You listed many things that "very few Orthodox Jews still hold." While it is true that some of those items belong on that list, others most definitely do not.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible that the difference in interest in the location of Mount Sinai and the Red Sea crossing among Jewish and non-Jewish people is due to the fact that Judaism is a religion that is still practiced today, while the locations of these events are seen more as historical or archeological sites by non-Jews. For many Jewish people, the events that took place at Mount Sinai and the Red Sea crossing are an important part of their religious beliefs and traditions, and so they may not have as much interest in the specific locations where these events took place.

Additionally, the location of Mount Sinai and the Red Sea crossing are not as central to the practice of Judaism as they are to other religions, such as Christianity, which places a great emphasis on the historical accuracy of the events described in the Bible. For this reason, non-Jewish people who are interested in the historical accuracy of the Bible may be more interested in the location of these events than Jewish people.

Overall, it's difficult to say why there is a difference in interest in these locations among Jewish and non-Jewish people, but it's possible that the reasons mentioned above play a role.

Comment: Please do not use ChatGPT to answer questions.

Comment: ah dang - you caught me :-( point taken